# How to get the options from a symfony select type

Tags: symfony

I have the following use case:

The user can select options from a dropdown, however if they want to choose something else they can choose 'other', this brings up a Javascript `prompt()` which is then added as an `option` to the `select` and selected.

[image: dropdown]

My question is around how to load this value into the select when the page is loaded. I can see that I can use

```
 $builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
```

to add the extra element to the list, but how can I get the list of existing elements? I'm sure I must not have to code them again, but I can't find the route to get the list of options.

Here's the class of the dropdown:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class HeatGeneratedFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array('choices'=> 
                array(
                    null=> 'Select',
                    'Grasses / Straw'   => 'Grasses / Straw',
                    'Wood Chip' => 'Wood Chip',
                    'Wood Logs'   => 'Wood Logs',
                    'Wood Pellets'   => 'Wood Pellets',
                    'Other' => 'Other'
                    )
                )
            );
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'HeatGenerated';
    }
}
```

So to rephrase my question, for this code:

```
if (!in_array($object->getHeatGenerated(), $form->get('heatGenerated')->getChoices()) {
    $form->get('heatGenerated')->addChoice($object->getHeatGenerated());
}
```

`->getChoices()` and `->addChoice()` aren't real methods, what do I use to get and edit the list of choices?

Comment: try $form->getConfig()->getOption('choices');

Comment: thanks @user2268997, that's great, is there a way to add an option?

Comment: I haven't found one.What I do is to add the field again with the new choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{  
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // other fields chopped
            ->add('myField', new CustomChoiceFormType()) // This type has the preset choices
            ;

            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $choices = $form->get('myField')->getConfig()->getOption('choices');
                $choice = $data->getMyField();

                if (!in_array($choice, $choices)) {
                    $newChoices = array_merge($choices, array($choice=>$choice)); // Need to add the key and the value, for me these are the same, but ofcourse they could be different

                    $form->remove('myField');
                    $form->add('myField', 'choice', array('choices'=>$newChoices));
                }

            });
    }
}
```